# ActiveRecord: Inserting data to the output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a few very basic questions in mind regarding active records. Please help me undestand:

1. What is the (data)type of the query result?
2. On doing '.class' to it, I get
   the class name (Model name) to which it belongs. Makes complete
   sense, but can we add more to the result?

Explaining my question with example:

```
u = User.find 1
=>#<User id: 1, email: "shivam@example.com", lang: 0, currency: 0, state: 0, category: 0, verified: true>
```

Checking the class:

```
u.class
=>User(id: integer, email: string, lang: integer, currency: integer, state: integer, category: integer, verified: boolean)
```

Is there someway to do this?

```
u.new_attr = "new_val"
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is your `new_attr`?
`find` returns an object of your model class. So: `Model.find(param)` returns `Model` instance.

Comment: It can be anything. I just want to add something to the result (not to the class).

Comment: You need to set some virtual attribute? Or a value of one of the columns in `users` table?

Comment: virtual attribute. I need to do the query from users table and then append some information to it.

Comment: You can create virtual attribute using simply `attr_accessor`.

Comment: @MarekLipka please excuse me if I am unable to explain myself clearly. What im asking is, after i do the query, I want to manipulate the result (this has nothing to do with Model now) and then pass it further in my application. Is that possible? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if my question was not self explanatory. Here's a short explanation:

- I do an active record query.
- I get results.
- I want to add something further to it.

As in the question the example is:

```
u = User.find 1
=>#<User id: 1, email: "shivam@example.com", lang: 0, currency: 0, state: 0, category: 0, verified: true>
```

**AIM**

To add some more information to the result set.

**ISSUE**

query result is an object of class `User`. As objects are instances of a class, we cannot simply add new attributes to the object without modifying the class. (Which is certainly not what we are looking for).

**SOLUTION**

It is plain stupidity to even think of directly modifying the object (which I did and got a -1 on my question. I acknowledge my mistake).

What we should rather do is, somehow convert the object into a data-structure that can be modified. In a case like this `Hash` suits the best.

Rails just provide an api to do so, its called [attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/attributes%3D). Here:

```
u = User.find 1
=>#<User id: 1, email: "shivam@example.com", lang: 0, currency: 0, state: 0, category: 0, verified: true>
u.attributes
=> {"id" => 1, "email" => "shivam@example.com", "lang" => 0, "currency" => 0, "state" => 0, "category" => 0, "verified" => true}
```

Now that we have a hash. we can easily add/remove/modify/append any thing we want to:

```
u.attributes.merge({"something" => "added"})
=> {"id" => 1, "email" => "shivam@example.com", "lang" => 0, "currency" => 0, "state" => 0, "category" => 0, "verified" => true, "something" => "added"}
```

PS: Silly as it may, I have seen a lot of people asking such question over SO and other communities. I hope this may help someone. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this is what you want to do, but you can just select extra fields and they will be available on the object.

An example to demonstrate this:

```
results = Sample.find_by_sql(<<-SQL
  select s.id, count(*) as results_count 
  from samples s, sample_results ss 
  where ss.sample_id = s.id 
  group by s.id
SQL)
```

So this query will return the sample-id and the count of linked sample-results. Now I can just type

```
results.first.results_count
```

and, obviously, `results_count` is not defined as attribute on the model `Sample`.

Not sure if that is what you ment. Maybe you just want to add an instance variable which is not saved to the database. In that case
you can simply do

```
class Sample

  attr_accessor :my_special_field

end
```

and now I can just write

```
sample.my_special_field = 'something'
```

and it will only be available as long as the object "exists" and is never saved to the database.